# Can't figure out how WEB API Calls URLS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm learning WEB API on ASP.NET web forms and already implementing it on my project to show some data on a modal but I can't figure out how is the api url created.

I followed this tutorial 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

this is my AJAX call

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowUserModal(lnk, IdColaborador) {

        debugger
        //var s = lnk.id;
        //var start = s.indexOf("lnkEdit");
        //var end = s.lastIndexOf("_");
        //sub = s.substring(start, end);
        //s = s.replace(sub, "IdMatriz");
        //var hidden = document.getElementById(s);
        //var id = hidden.value;
        //alert(id);

        var uri = 'api/users/';

        $.ajax({

            URL: uri,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: IdColaborador,
            success: function (data) {

                alert("Saved successfully");
            },
            fail: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            }

        })
    }        
</script>
```

this is my controller

```
 public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    public User user { get; set; }


    //public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
    //{

    //    return users;
    //}

    public IHttpActionResult GetUser(int id)
    {
        user = new User();

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ControloInterno_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spOperadores", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "SELECTINF");                   
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdColaborador", id);

                con.Open();
                using(SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        user.Nome = sdr["Nome"].ToString();
                        user.Criador = sdr["criador"].ToString();
                        user.DataAdm = Convert.ToDateTime(sdr["dataadmin"]);
                        user.AltData = Convert.ToDateTime(sdr["AltData"]);
                        user.Telemovel = sdr["tele"].ToString();
                        user.Departamento = sdr["Departamento"].ToString();
                        user.status = sdr["status"].ToString();
                        user.DescricaoPerfil = sdr["DescricaoPerfil"].ToString();
                        user.Observacoes = sdr["Observacoes"].ToString();
                    }
                }                                    
            }
        }

        return Ok(user);
    }
}
```

and I had to use this in global.asax to work

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

so my question is, how is the url generated? why is it called api/users if my controller is called UsersController and the class is called User

Comment: It uses the template and the name of your controller.

routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}" --> your controllers name is Users(Controller) thus you get api/users

You can also use attribute routing, just try to apply [Route("api/[controller]")] attribute above your controller class declaration and [Route("getusers")] etc. above each endpoint method. This would result in a url as follows:: localhost:xxx/api/users/getusers

Comment: I tried to do this,  [Route("api/[controller]")] on top of controller class and [Route("GetUser/{id}")] on the method, however it does not work, I call it with api/users/GetUser/5.  I also commetned what i had in global.asax but then i tried to change the url in global asax and I added "api/{controller}/{Action}/{id}"and it worked when i typed api/users/getUser/16

Answer (score 1):

If you are using attribute routing make sure you call the following function on your HttpConfiguration:

```
  // Web API routes
  config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

You can read more about attribute routing here:
[Web api attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)
Or if you will use MVC instead read here:
[Attribute routing in MVC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)